# Cannot read property 'setRowData' of undefined

Tags: angular2-services, ag-grid

I am trying to get new data on my ag grid. I tried using

```
this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(rowdata);
```

but it throws this error

> Cannot read property 'setRowData' of undefined

I have kept this method in the `onGridReady` method at the `onInit` method.
Not sure if that helps, but I am using `cellRenderer` also.

Does this method work for anyone else?

Is there anything specific to call this method?

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Answer (score 5):

The gridReady event has the api as a parameter. Try event.api.setRowData(), or set the row data using the rowData property instead.

Comment: "`The gridReady event has the api as a parameter`" - I wish that I could upvote this multiple times!  Where did you find that? I don't see it in the docs.

Comment: Could you explain more about this? I am having the same trouble getting the GridApi to work. gridOptions.api seems to initialize just fine. I am trying to run tests between how data is set using both apis

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error when I did not add this line

modules = AllCommunityModules;

Hope this will help.

Comment: Where did you and that? And was this AngularJs, or Angular?

Comment: It was an Angular 8